# how to self join a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

After Updating query i got following output with this query

i am writing following query to put two sets of records next to each other.

```
 WITH cte AS
  (SELECT SubSubsidaryAccountCode,
          sum(Debit) AS debit,
          sum(Credit) AS credit,
          ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY SubSubsidaryAccountCode
                             ORDER BY SubSubsidaryAccountCode) AS RN
   FROM TBLLedgerLevel4
   WHERE SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '4%'
     OR SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '5%'
   GROUP BY SubSubsidaryAccountCode ),
     cte2 AS
  (SELECT *
   FROM TBLLevel4)
SELECT a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode ,
       c.SubSubsidaryAccountName AS RevenuName ,
       sum(a.Debit) AS debit ,
       b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode AS SubsidaryAccount2 ,
       d.SubSubsidaryAccountName AS ExpenseName ,
       sum(b.Credit) AS credit
FROM cte a
JOIN cte2 c ON a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode = c.SubSubsidaryAccountCode
FULL JOIN cte b ON a.RN = b.RN
JOIN cte2 d ON b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode=d.SubSubsidaryAccountCode
WHERE a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '4%'
  AND b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode LIKE '5%'
GROUP BY a.SubSubsidaryAccountCode,
         b.SubSubsidaryAccountCode,
         c.SubSubsidaryAccountName,
         d.SubSubsidaryAccountName
```

**Output:**

```
 SubSubsidaryAccountCode    RevenuName  debit   SubsidaryAccount2   ExpenseName credit
     4-106-1001-10026        Cash Sale  52889    5-105-1005-10011   Rf Battles  18091289
     4-108-1012-10037        New Sale1  1000     5-105-1005-10011   Rf Battles  18091289
```

The above output contains records against two Accounting codes that starts with 4 and 5 .Now the records against accounting code that are starting with accounting code like 4 are populated and are according to desired results but the 2nd row of record starting with accounting code 5 does not have any value and must have null value in it.Please help me out to solve this problem.

Comment: First, you should decide which database you are using . . . SQL Server or MySQL?

Comment: @GordonLinoff  sql server

Comment: i have removed the tag of my sql

Comment: Are you saying you want to display the four records you already have (where MyAccountId = 4) and also display one more record where MyAccountId = 5? Just aiming to clarify

Comment: What determines which one is populated and which ones are `NULL`?

Comment: Cartesian Joins and Joins are a bit different.  You might want to clarify that in your question

Comment: yes because id=5 contains only one record so i want remaining four rows to have null values

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil may you show us some desired results?

Comment: @everyone . I have mentioned in my question that id=4 contains five records and id=5 contains one record so i want to display 5 records against id=4 and one record against id=5

Comment: @JeffOrris i have shown the output of query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sample makes it seem like it's arbitrary which ones are populated and which are `NULL`, like you just want to put two sets of records next to each other.  You could do that by adding a `ROW_NUMBER()` and using that in a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MainAccountID ORDER BY LedgerDate) AS RN
              FROM TBLLedgerLevel1
              )
    SELECT  a.LedgerDate
          , a.MainAccountId
          , a.VoucherCode
          , a.Debit
          , b.LedgerDate AS Date2
          , b.MainAccountId AS MainAccount2
          , b.VoucherCode AS VoucherCode2
          , b.Credit  
      FROM cte a 
      LEFT JOIN cte b   
        ON a.RN = b.RN 
         and b.MainAccountId='5' 
      WHERE  a.MainAccountId='4'
```

If there could be more `MainAccountId='5'` records than `MainAccountId='4'` you'd probably want a `FULL JOIN` and could use `COALESCE()` to choose which field to display.  Also, making use of aliases cleans up code significantly in my opinion.

Update:  Not sure exactly on this, but to add the name you'll need to add a `JOIN` to `TBLLevel1`, something like:

```
;with cte AS (SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY MainAccountID ORDER BY LedgerDate) AS RN
              FROM TBLLedgerLevel1
              )
    SELECT  a.LedgerDate
          , a.MainAccountId
          , a.VoucherCode
          , a.Debit
          , b.LedgerDate AS Date2
          , b.MainAccountId AS MainAccount2
          , b.VoucherCode AS VoucherCode2
          , b.Credit  
              , c.MainAccountName
      FROM cte a 
      JOIN TBLLevel1 c
         ON a.MainAccountID = c.ID
      LEFT JOIN cte b   
        ON a.RN = b.RN 
         and b.MainAccountId='5' 
      WHERE  a.MainAccountId='4'
```

If there's more than 1 record per `MainAccountId` in the `TBLLevel1` table you'll need to add criteria to the `JOIN` to make sure only the proper value is included.

Comment: can you please help to get my main account Name from TBLLevel1 as mainAccountId=4 has MainAccountName=Revenue. How can i retrieve this information using above query?

Comment: You should be able to just add the field to the `SELECT` list, it's not clear from your question where the proper name would come from, some sample data might be needed.

Comment: the name would come from another table named as TBLLevel1 which contains id=4 and name= revenue

Comment: Can you please edit your answer how can i use another select using above query

Comment: @sheikhmuzammil Overall the table structure isn't clear, but see updated for an idea of how to incorporate.

Comment: i am editing my question again with the changes i have made in query but still getting issue please help me and point out where i am making mistake